# Vector Cross Product in Mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors

$\vec{v(t)}\ =\frac{4t^{3}}{15}\hat{i} \ -\frac{3}{10} t^{2}\hat{j}$

$\vec{r(t)} \ =\ \frac{t^{4}}{15}\hat{i} -\frac{t^{3}}{10}\hat{j}$

Find
$\displaystyle \vec{r} \ \times \ \vec{v}$

I am working on the Kleppnor and Kolenkow mechanics book, in chapter two I am asked to find two vectors and then their cross product. I found the vectors successfully but cannot figure out the cross product correctly.

Both of these vectors are correct and I tried to find the cross product as the determinant of a 2 x 2 matrix. The solution (they used the determinant of a 3 x 3 matrix) has a vector with only i and j components. **I don't understnad how the cross product of two vectors both in the x-y plane leads to a vector that doesn't have a z-component.**
My understanding of cross product is that it determines a vector perpendicular to both of the vectors, is this wrong?

Comment: Can you edit this calculation into your answer? I agree with you that $\vec{r}\times\vec{v}$ should have a $\hat{k}$ component (indeed, _only_ that).

Comment: This is a mistake in the K&K solutions manual.

Comment: "The solution (they used the determinant of a 3 x 3 matrix) has a vector with only i and j components. I don't understnad how the cross product of two vectors both in the x-y plane leads to a vector that doesn't have a z-component." The solution is wrong. There can only be a z component of $\vec r \times \vec v$ since $\hat i \times \hat j = \hat k$, $\hat j \times \hat i = -\hat k$, $\hat i \times \hat i = 0$, and $\hat j \times \hat j=0$

Answer (score 1):

The cross product in 2 dimensions is different from a cross product in 3 dimensions. For a deep understanding: see Geometric Algebra.

In 3 dimensions, the cross product can be written as:

$$ (a \times b)_i = \epsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k $$

where the indices run over $(1,2,3)$, or, if you prefer: $(x, y, z)$. ($ijk$ are not directions, they're indices).

For instance, if we pick $i=x$, that gives the $x$ component of the cross product:

$$ (a \times b)_x = \epsilon_{1jk}a_jb_k =(a_yb_z-a_zb_y)$$

Now, that's the component. If you want a vector, multiple by the $x$ basis vector $\hat e_x$, so the general formula is:

$$ \vec a \times \vec b = (\epsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k)\hat e_i $$

Note that the RHS is the determinant of a matrix with rows equal to $\vec a$, $\vec b$, and $(\hat e_x, \hat e_y, \hat e_z)$.

This works out because the vectors have 3 components and the are 3 rows. It makes a square matrix, for which a determinant can be defined.

With only 2 components, that's not going to work. Of course, the cross product will only have a non-zero "$z$"-component anyway, which is not even in the 2-dimensional bases. (See: Geometric Algebra).

If you want to solve it in 3 dimensions, do the determinant with the $0\hat e_z$ terms explicitly.

In 2 dimensional, the formula is:

$$ (a \times b) = \epsilon_{ij}a_ib_k $$

Note that in any dimension, $\epsilon_{ij\cdots lm}$ is $\pm 1$ for (anti)symmetric permutations of ${ij\cdot lm}$ and zero otherwise.